# Has a player ever obtained a 147 via two breaks?

Tags: trivia, snooker

Suppose John starts a break and gets red-black combinations to a reasonable score, then misses red. Paul takes his shot next but misses straight away, scoring nothing. John takes his next break and continues until his total score is 147.

Has this ever happened before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure it has, but it doesn't really mean anything. It's not a meaningful achievement and wouldn't have been noted. A "147" is a break of 147, as a "century" is scoring 100 points in one turn - anyone could score 100 points in multiple turns.